# Lagrange's equation for a $N$ identical masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism

[image]

The question above includes a Lagrangian whose equation of motion is required. The equation of motion can be worked out by
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x_n}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_n} = 0;$$
however, I do not get the solution shown above, especially the part where an extra $x_{n-1}$ term comes in from.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you perchance write something like
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_n} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mu x_n^2-\frac{1}{2}\nu(x_{n+1}-x_n)^2\right) =-\mu x_n + \nu(x_{n+1}-x_n)$$
in your calculations? The first equality here is incorrect. Try using a different name than $n$ for the index, so that you don't confuse it with the summation index, and really think about the terms in the sum. I.e.
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_k} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\dots\right),$$
and maybe think it through for a specific index first, say $k=1$.

Note also that there is a small mistake in the given answer. It is missing a factor of $m$ on the left hand side and should actually read
$$m\ddot x_n = -\mu x_n + \nu(x_{n+1} + x_{n-1} - 2x_n).$$

Comment: Yes, I performed the first equality. If I were to take your advice, then I suppose I would be have to perform a chain rule on the term in hand but I still do not understand where the change in index from $n$ to $n-1$ comes from.

Comment: @GitGoodCodes Hmm, I do not know what you mean about having to use the chain rule. Try this: write out the first two terms of the sum in $L$ explicitly. Now, how many $x_1$-terms do you see?

Comment: I see! So the summation for n = 1 includes the $x_{n-1}$ term as well as an additional $x_n$ term, is that why?

Comment: @GitGoodCodes Well, not quite, but I think you've got the right idea. Say we are taking the derivative $\partial L/\partial x_k$, so we are looking for terms in $L$ containing $x_k$. Then, of course, we note that the $n=k$ term in the sum contains both $-(1/2)\mu x_k^2$ and $-(1/2)\nu(x_{k+1}-x_k)$. These are the terms you found and included in your calculations. But, additionally, the $n=k-1$ term contains  $-(1/2)\nu(x_{(k-1)+1}-x_{k-1})=-(1/2)\nu(x_k-x_{k-1})$, and this is the one you missed!

Comment: Ahh I see, your previous hints lead me close to the correct logic. This makes a lot of sense. Many thanks!

Comment: @GitGoodCodes The trick you might be missing is how to represent $\partial x_n/\partial x_m$ in a useful way. The Kronecker delta $\delta_{nm}$ is 1 when $n$ and $m$ are the same and zero otherwise.